# Operator overloading for two different types of same templated class/structure?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading

I have a convenient class, *Vector*. It is really just a templated structure that holds 3 things. They can be floats, doubles, ints, etc.

IE:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector 
{
 T x;
 T y;
 T z;
}
```

It has nice operator overloading, allowing me to add two vectors together, for example:

```
Vector operator+(const Vector& rhs) 
{
 return Vector(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y, z + rhs.z);
}
```

However, what if I want to do this:

```
Vector<float> myFloatVec(0.2, 0.5, 0.95);
Vector<int> myIntVec(2, 5, 1);

Vector<float> result = myFloatVec + myIntVec; // cannot do this
```

And what if I later wanted to change types:

```
vector<int> result2 = static_cast<int>(result); // cannot do, this would be nice too
```

Is there any way to accomplish something like that easily in C++?

If I could somehow cast the integer vector into a float vector, then I could let the normal operator overloading take over. Sadly, I do not know of any way to overload how static_cast<> works on a type.

Comment: It does seem to be on the right track, somehow missed it. Though the answer is a bit confusing, since it doesn't seem to actually be performing a ```+=``, not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: Your code doesn't have a `+=`, so I don't see the problem

Comment: You could add another overload for a specific type of vector I.e `Vector<T> operator+(const Vector<int>& rhs)` or even `Vector<T> operator+(const U& rhs)`. Though to be honest I don't think I'd involve templates at all, would probably just have two separate types instead with explicitly named functions where any conversion has to happen.

Comment: @TylerShellberg Fair enough. Probably a typo on the answerer's part. But the point is the same. Whether it's `+`, `+=`, `-`, or `%=`, your problem is with your declaration, not the actual content of the function.

Comment: @Chipster: Not on the answerer's part; the original question's example code wasn't doing a `+=`-like operation either. But the body of the `+=` is largely irrelevant; you implement it in whatever way seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include<type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Vector 
{
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator +( const Vector<T1> &v1, const Vector<T2> &v2 ) -> Vector<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type>
{
    return { v1.x + v2. x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z };  
}

int main() 
{
    Vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    Vector<float> v2 = { 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f };

    Vector<float> v3 = v1 + v2;

    std::cout << "v3.x = " << v3.x 
              << ", v3.y = " << v3.y
              << ", v3.z = " << v3.z 
              << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
v3.x = 2.1, v3.y = 4.2, v3.z = 6.3
```

Comment: What about the `vector<int> result2 = static_cast<int>(result);`?

Comment: I would probably also use `std::typeof(std::declval<T1>()+std::declval<T2>())` instead of `common_type`, in order to handle any other weird overloads (aka `vector<vector<int>>`

Comment: @MooingDuck In this case for example a template conversion constructor is required.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow What's the main difference between this approach and templating the operator overload with only a single argument, like the other approach people have linked does?

Comment: @TylerShellberg Usually binary operators are declared as non-class functions.

Comment: He could add `template<class U> explicit operator Vector<U>() {...}` to allow explicit conversions, but yes, a constructor would be better.